# Tensorflow stuck on first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu, conda

My execution is stuck on the following step
I got GTX 3090 on Python 3.7 on windows 10. I installed cuda, cudnn and tensorflow-gpu using conda as instructed from here

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.3 tensorflow=2.3=mkl_py37h936c3e2_0
```

Can someone please tell me why is it stuck at this step?

```
2021-04-01 10:09:38.147949: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Warning, `split` argument is replaced by `split_val`, please condider to change your source code.The `split` argument will be removed in future releases.
class 0, validation count: 68, train count: 159
class 5, validation count: 83, train count: 195
Total data: 2 classes for 354 files for train
Total data: 2 classes for 151 files for validation
2021-04-01 10:09:40.046207: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.763173: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:44:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 24.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2021-04-01 10:09:40.763755: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA Quadro P1000 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.5185GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 89.53GiB/s
2021-04-01 10:09:40.764222: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.768538: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.772484: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.774033: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.778690: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.781972: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.793304: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.793720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1843] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 1, name: NVIDIA Quadro P1000, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) with core count: 4. The minimum required count is 8. You can adjust this requirement with the env var TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT.
2021-04-01 10:09:40.794339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-04-01 10:09:40.795239: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-04-01 10:09:40.808243: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2af71215370 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-04-01 10:09:40.808648: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2021-04-01 10:09:40.809155: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:44:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 24.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2021-04-01 10:09:40.809789: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.810112: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.810416: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.810728: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.811035: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.811338: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.811624: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:40.811974: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-04-01 10:09:42.137546: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-04-01 10:09:42.137800: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2021-04-01 10:09:42.137935: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2021-04-01 10:09:42.138228: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 19112 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090, pci bus id: 0000:44:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-04-01 10:09:42.141792: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2af27c8f640 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-04-01 10:09:42.142075: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090, Compute Capability 8.6
Epoch 1/1000
2021-04-01 10:09:46.249137: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-04-01 10:09:47.132659: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
```

And here my dependencies

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.4            py37hcc03f2d_0    conda-forge
astor                     0.8.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             3.0.1                   py_1000    conda-forge
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37hcc03f2d_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py37hd8e9650_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py37h03978a9_1    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py37h20c650d_0    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h3826478_8    conda-forge
cudnn                     7.6.5.32             h36d860d_1    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.3.3                      py_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.28.0             pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.36.1           py37h04d2302_0    conda-forge
h5py                      2.10.0          nompi_py37h23cfb99_105    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h5268f04_1114    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        3.10.0           py37h03978a9_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2020.3             h57928b3_311    conda-forge
keras                     2.4.3                      py_0    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras-video-generators    1.0.14                   pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.17.2               hbae68bd_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.76.0               hf1763fc_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.15.6               h7755175_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                h680486a_6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2020.4             hb70f87d_311    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
multidict                 5.1.0            py37hcc03f2d_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.5           py37hd20adf4_1    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
opencv-python             4.5.1.48                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1k               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pillow                    8.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.15.6           py37hf2a7229_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyreadline                2.1             py37h03978a9_1003    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37h03978a9_3    conda-forge
python                    3.7.10          h7840368_100_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.6.2            py37h924764e_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py37h03978a9_3    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.35.3               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.3.0           mkl_py37h936c3e2_0
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           gpu_py37h18d21e4_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0              pyh9656e83_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            2.3.0                he13fc11_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                       0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_4    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.28.29325          h5e1d092_4    conda-forge
werkzeug                  1.0.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py37h03978a9_2    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2             py37h03978a9_1006    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37hcc03f2d_3    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0    conda-forge
yarl                      1.6.3            py37hcc03f2d_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h62dcd97_1010    conda-forge
```

UPDATE:
The same exact code worked on the 2080TI, I switched it with the 3090 which I just got and did a fresh environment and uninstalled all 2080TI related software.

Here is model

```
Total params: 5,502,338 
Trainable params: 5,500,418 
Non-trainable params: 1,920
```

I also added `CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE=2147483648` to my enviornment variables.

Comment: How long the step will take depends a lot on your model size. Can you please add the output of `model.summary()` to your question.

Comment: @Christian updated question

Comment: I used `keras` instead of `tensorflow.keras` and it worked. So must be conflict with TF and Keras versions.

Comment: yes, I have experienced the same behaviour. I uninstalled plain keras in my tf environments and use `from tensorflow import keras`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RTX 2080 Ti` cards are based on `Turing` architecture for which compatible `CUDA version start with 10.x`, where as `RTX 3090` cards are based on the `Ampere` architecture for which compatible `CUDA version start with 11.x`.

So compatible Tensorflow version for your gpu card is `2.4.0`. For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).